# Action on item in Toolbar?

Tags: android, xml

I have `ToolbarCustom` that has two items and an item can be clicked to open or close the layout. I am wondering how can I use the same item for opening and closing layout?

This my Code, but the variable `openLayout` is not defined:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.show);
        boolean openLayout=true;
        if (id == R.id.action_categure) {
            if (openLayout) {
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                openLayout=false;
            } else  {
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                openLayout =true;
            }

        }
        if (id==R.id.action_card){

          return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: try to use shared preference on menu item click , check value on click from shared preference , if value is 0 then show , update value to 1 after . now 2nd time it check if value is 1 then not show . and update value to 0.

Comment: linearLayout.setVisibility(rootView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE ?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

```
 boolean firstTimeClick = true;  //global variable
 boolean secondTimeClick = false;  //global variable

 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.show);

    if (id == R.id.action_categure) {
        if (firstTimeClick) {
            firstTimeClick = false;
            secondTimeClick= true;
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else if (secondTimeClick){
            firstTimeClick= true;
            secondTimeClick= false;
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
   }
    if (id==R.id.action_card){

      return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Is that what you want to achieve?Hope I helped you.

Comment: Not defined variable , firstTimeClick and secondTimeClick.

Comment: put them in onOptionsItemSelected then